# String comparison with ==

Tags: c, if-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//CALLBACKS
void infoCallback(){
    system("cheese");
}
void wgetCallback(char *website){
    if(website == NULL)
        printf("\nSITIO WEB NO INGRESADO!\n");
    else{
        printf("%s \n", website);
        system("echo making wget success");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("\tAUTO-BASH\n");

    printf("%s \n", argv[1]);

    if(argv[1] == "-w"){
        wgetCallback(argv[2]);
    }
    else if(argv[1] == "-i"){
        infoCallback();
    }
    else{
        printf("\nsos un noob\n");
    }
}
```

It doesn't do what i want.... if i write -w, it goes to else.
...
i want to make a switch(any type){
case "??":
but i don't know why i couldn't do this.

Comment: Check value of argv[1] and maybe  you need to cast it to string

Comment: `"-w"` is a constant. `argv[1]` is a variable. A pointer to a variable is not going to equal a pointer to a constant since they cannot possibly point to the same thing since something cannot be both a variable and a constant.

Comment: @David Schwartz Technically disagree with "not going to equal".  Although not so applicable to `argv[]`, consider `char *s = "-w"; if (s == "-w")...`.  In this case, the compare could be true as code could fold both `"-w"` to the same address - or it might not.  IAC, not a good programming practice.

Answer (score 3):

1. Compare string is done using `strcmp`
2. switch only works with ordinal type

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare C strings with ==. Use [`strcmp`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm).

```
if(strcmp(argv[1],"-w") == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Step back for a moment.  In C, what is a *string*?

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.
>   C11 §7.1.1 1

A *string* is not a pointer and not an address, but a sequence of characters such an an array or a *string literal*.

To compare *strings*, code needs to compare the content of those arrays.  Use `strcmp()`.

```
// compares pointers - not a string compare
if(argv[1] == "-w") {

// compares content - a string compare
if (strcmp(argv[1], "-w") == 0) {
```

`argv[1] == "-w"` compares pointers, not the content they point to.

`strcmp(argv[1], "-w")` takes the value of `argv[1]`, a `char *` and the address of the *string literal* `"-w"`, also a `char *` and uses those 2 to beginning comparing `char`-by-`char` until a difference of a null character is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare character arrays in C with == and C doesn't support `operator overloading`. You have to use `standard library function` `strcmp()` or make your own function.

For Example,

```
if (!strcmp(argv[1],"-w"))
```

But you can compare two characters using `==` operator. You can try this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void infoCallback()
{
   printf("cheese\n");
}

void wgetCallback()
{
   printf("website\n");
}

int singleCharOpt(char *opt)
{
   if (*(opt+1) != '\0') {
       printf("Not a Valid Single Character Option\n");
       return -1;
   }
   if(*opt == 'w') {
       wgetCallback();
    } else if(*opt == 'i') {
        infoCallback();
    } else {
        printf("Unknown Option\n");
    }
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   /* Do Something */
   printf("Hello options\n");

   if (argc <= 1)
       return 0;
   int i;
   for (i=1; i<argc; i++ ) {
       printf("Option: %s\n", argv[i]);
       char *opt = argv[i];

       int result = (*opt == '-') ? singleCharOpt(++opt) : -1;

       if (result)
           printf("Wrong Option\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```